# ssh forward - bidirectional

Tags: ssh, forward, bidirectional

When using ssh forwarding Im able to commit with cvs and ftp against a remote server. Is it possible to let the server initiate a request against my machine - I would like the web application on the server to call a REST method on my machine.

Thanks.
Nikolaj G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, provided you know your local machine's IP address and your HTTP port (default 80) is open, AND you have a service able to interpret the REST request, then yes. It's important to note you will have to have access to the remote machine to initiate the request, so it's not "really" bidirectional. I'm assuming that when you say "REST method" you mean this rest:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

[Edit]

ssh does in fact have a bidirectionality to its tunnels!

use `ssh` with  `-L [port]:[host]:[rport]` for a forward tunnel and `-R [port]:[host]:[port]` for the reverse tunnel. I always screw up the order of the ports and am not sure how -R wants them, so do yourselves a favor and check out the man pages for ssh:

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1

or type `man ssh` in your favorite (or the sysadmin's favorite) terminal shell.

Comment: Hi Kasapo, the setup is like this. Im making a REST server (java) and a php web solution. The php solution is deployed to a linux box for test (apache). Im having a ssh tunnel to this linux server and is currently deploying with ftp (cvs also works). The problem is that the php web solution is contacting a 3rd machines REST facade (which I do not have access to). I would like to let the php solution contact my REST server. I was thinking - is it possible to use the ssh tunnel back to my machine? I have full control on my own machine and user login to the linux box. Thanks. Nikolaj

Comment: are you using "ssh -L [localport]:[host]:[remoteport]"? I read that you can use ssh -R to do the same thing backwards (bi-directionally). I never knew you could do such a thing. I would try "ssh -L ... -R ...", filling in the relevant values. I've never tried it but it might work for you, here's the link to the post I saw and the SSH man page:
http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=90532
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1

Comment: Hi Kasapo, it is working now with "ssh -R ...". Thanks. Nikolaj